# Curie's principle in electromagnetic field theory

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, electrostatics, symmetry

I am looking for some explanation and if possible also some references about the applications of [Curie's principle](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&as_q=curie+dissymmetry+principle) in electromagnetic field Theory, precisely in the computation of magnetic (resp. electric) fields generated by different configurations, like the infinite wire, the cylindrical, the spherical or even more complicated configurations (in an undergraduate context), that is I'm looking for "laws"/"approaches" to handle symmetries and invariances in the many differents situations I'm faced with.

EDIT : what I mean by that is how to exploit the symmetries and invariances of a certain configuration to determine in what composent the field depend and in what direction(s) it propagate.

Comment: The basic idea is that if your source has a particular symmetry imagine a field configuration then perform a symmetry operation on it (translation, rotation, reflection). If the field changes it's no good. That's because the source is unchanged but the field it is supposed to produce *is* changed, so how is nature supposed to decide which field to produce? With a bit of practice and visualisation you can narrow down the possibilities a lot in your head.

Comment: do you have any references that illustrate the aplications of this principle in EM theory since i've googled it before and i did not find anything .

Comment: I've never heard it called "Curie's principle" before, but symmetry arguments are used all the time. You shouldn't have any troubles finding examples in any EM textbook.